# Rails: load a html.haml file and render it in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

How to load a html.haml file from a custom class, store in a var its data, then apply some instance variables and render it in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description of the problem is light on details, but I think your HAML file should be a partial, and you can just use

```
render :partial => "<your file name>", :locals => {:foo => 'bar'}
```

in your view, and pass the variables you want via :locals.

There is a description of working with partials in [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).